# Expose one whole object or several properties of that object?

Tags: object-oriented-design, properties

I'm currently refactoring on an older project, which has classes that expose both a single object and also multiple properties from that object. Ex:

```
public class Foo
{    
    private MyObj myObj;
    public IMyObj Bar
    {
        get
        {
            return myObj;
        }  
     }         

     public int SomeProperty
     {
        get
        {
            return Bar.SomeProperty;
        }
     }
}
```

In other classes, sometimes `SomeProperty` is used, sometimes the property is accessed via `Bar.SomeProperty`. I thinks that's super confusing since it is not always directly clear if `SomeProperty` belongs to the class itself or an underlying object. Is one or the other preferable over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any public property like this becomes part of the type's public API. According to the open/closed principle, it shouldn't ever change, even if the underlying code does. By exposing `Bar` through a public property, you are therefore forcing `IMyObj` to become part of that public API too. In the future, if you then decide the `obj` should implement `IMyNewObj` instead, you either have to have the latter inherit from the former, or `MyObj` must implement both `IMyObj` and `IMyNewObj` in order to avoid changing the `Bar` property. You've coupled your class' inner workings to other types and its API.

By adopting the `public int SomeProperty` route, that property is free to change in future to `return Baz.SomeCompletelyDifferentProperty;` without affecting the API. You have therefore decoupled the inner workings and types from the API.

So I'd argue the latter is the better approach. The caveat of course is pragmatism: if `IMyObj` has lots of properties, you end up replicating those in the API, making the code cumbersome. Often this is a sign that `Foo` and `IObj` are doing too many things; but not always. So judgement is needed on a case-by-case basis as to whether this really is the better approach for that case.